# query to count the number of customers who spend more than > $20 by month

Tags: sql

For the below table, need a query to count the number of customers who spend more than > $20 by month.

[image]
I tried the below queries but I am told the output is not correct and not sure what the output should be.

Q1
select
month(payment_ts) as "Mon",
count(customer_id) as "Total"
from payment
where amount>20

Q2
select
month(payment_ts) as "Mon",
count(customer_id) as "Total"
from payment
group by 1
having sum(amount)>20

what is the correct query?

Comment: ```select month(payment_ts) as "Mon", count(customer_id) as "Total" from payment where amount>20 group by month(payment_ts)``` it's hard to say without the output of the table and what the "is not correct" means

Comment: If you're *not sure what the output should be* then.....who is?

Comment: this is an interview question and I am told the query is wrong. I wasn't provided with a dataset and I am told queries are wrong. Hence, I posted the question here.

Comment: I am told below query is also wrong
-->
select 
year(payment_ts),
month(payment_ts),
count(customer_id) over(partition by month(payment_ts))
from payment
where amount > 20

Answer (score 0):

The question might have been > $20 in total per month, so:

```
SELECT month(payment_ts) as "Mon", SUM(amount) as "Total", customer_id
FROM Payment
GROUP BY month(payment_ts), customer_id
HAVING SUM(amount) > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(Year from payment_ts) as year, Extract(Month from payment_ts) as mon, count(customer_id) OVER (PARTITION BY Extract(Month from payment_ts)) as count FROM payment group by EXTRACT(Year from payment_ts),Extract(Month from payment_ts),customer_id having sum(amount) > 20 order by year desc, mon;

Comment: Try using the code formatting tool and adding some supporting information